# char array not comparing properly java

Tags: java, arrays, char

This is a bit weird, but my java code won't compare chars properly.

I have this piece of code which loops through a 2D array of chars and replaces every 'I' with 'D'

```
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {
            if (activeGrid[i][j] == 'I')
            {
                activeGrid[i][j] = 'D';
                System.out.println("Changing [" + i + "][" + j + "]");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No I in [" + i + "][" + j + "]");
            }
        }
    }
```

However it does not seem to be working correctly, here's a sample run:

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B
   _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
0 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
1 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
2 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
3 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
4 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
5 | | | | | |D| | | | | | |
6 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
7 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
8 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
9 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
10 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
11 | | | | | | | | | | | | |

   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B
   _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
0 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
1 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
2 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
3 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
4 | | | | | |I| | | | | | |
5 | | | | |I|D|I| | | | | |
6 | | | | | |I| | | | | | |
7 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
8 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
9 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
10 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
11 | | | | | | | | | | | | |
```

(I have removed the "No I in..." parts for readablitiy)

It then refuses to update from here, no mater how many times I try to get it to, it wont change the I's to D's. Just to be even more confusing, sometimes it will change some or all I's, and then get stuck later on

I also see similar things with other parts of the code, one part checks each cell neighbouring a D and decides if the D's should spread or not, one of the factors for not spreading is if there is a D or I in the cell already, however in some cells I see the value switching from D to I each time I press enter and I also see random I's appearing in a sea of D's

Any ideas?

[EDIT]

Active grid was initialised like this:

```
public char[][] setActiveGrid (int x, int y)
{
    char grid[][] = new char [12][12];
    int Px;
    int Py;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
    grid[x][y] = 'D';
    do
    {
        Px = (int) Math.ceil((Math.random() * 12) - 1);
        Py = (int) Math.ceil((Math.random() * 12) - 1);
    } while (Px == x && Py == y);
    //grid[Px][Py] = 'P';

    return grid;
}
```

And it only gets changed by this:

```
public char[][] spreadDisease (char regionGrid[][], char activeGrid[][])
{
    char regionFlag;
    int i;
    int j;
    int xDiff;
    int yDiff;

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {
            if (activeGrid[i][j] == 'D')
            {
                regionFlag = regionGrid[i][j];

                for (xDiff = -1; xDiff < 2; xDiff = xDiff + 2)
                {
                    if (regionGrid[(i+xDiff)][j] == regionFlag && (activeGrid[(i+xDiff)][j] != 'D' || activeGrid[(i+xDiff)][j] != 'I'))
                    {
                        activeGrid[(i+xDiff)][j] = 'X';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        activeGrid[(i+xDiff)][j] = 'Y';
                    }
                }
                for (yDiff = -1; yDiff < 2; yDiff = yDiff + 2)
                {
                    if (regionGrid[i][(j+yDiff)] == regionFlag && (activeGrid[i][(j+yDiff)] != 'D' || activeGrid[(i+xDiff)][j] != 'I'))
                    {
                        activeGrid[i][(j+yDiff)] = 'X';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        activeGrid[i][(j+yDiff)] = 'Y';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return activeGrid;
}
```

regionGrid is a 2D char array filled with a randomised assortment of + - * and ~. The rules for the D's spreading are:

- If the cells neighbouring a D have the same region char as the D then they get set to D
- Otherwise they get set to I, and then set to D next run.

Comment: the for loop looks ok.. what value are you putting in activeGrid

Comment: The replacement loop can't be the problem because the logic is so simple (if that is literally what it looks like).

Comment: The snippet provided looks fine. We'd need more info to help...

Comment: show how you initialized `activeGrid`

Comment: Your edit does NOT show the initialization of `activeGrid`. Show how ActiveGrid gets its values.

Comment: Sorry, the actual initialisation lines don't add any data, so I didn't bother showing them, here they are

`char actvGrid[][] = new char[12][12];
actvGrid = grid.setActiveGrid(5,5);`

Comment: SO the first grid in your drawing is activegrid right? And the second grid is how you want activegrid to look after run?

Comment: Nearly, the code is looped through, the first drawing was the "initialisation" run, the second was the first iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since it works once and then appears not to work again, it's almost certain that you are not swapping buffers correctly for subsequent iterations.  The algorithm you'll want to use is:

```
Declare two 12x12 regions a and b.
Initialize a
number_of_generations = 0
loop
  Using a as source, compute spread with b as destination
  display b
  break if ++number_of_generations == limit
  Using b as source, compute spread with a as destination
  display a
  break if ++number_of_generations == limit
end loop
```

Comment: So use two arrays for the `activeGrrid`, switching between each one?

Comment: Oh and just to note, sometimes it works more than once. some times it stops with places where the D's should be spread but haven't for no apparent reason.

Comment: @user168057 Yes.  Compute from one buffer into another.  Your spread rules will get confused if they're referring to changes you made in previously processed cells.

Comment: I've already found a way around that issue. Instead of placing D's and I's in the array during the spreading process, I place X's and Y's respectively. Then once spreading is finished I replace all X's with D's and all Y's with I's

Comment: @user168057  Well, you may think this, but it's not true.

Comment: Could you explain further please?